# Deriving a formula related to the grand canonical ensemble

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics

I want to show the formula $(\frac{\partial\mu}{\partial N})_{V,T} = -\frac{V^2}{N^2}(\frac{\partial p}{\partial V})_{N,T} $ on a grand canonical ensemble case. But how can I prove this?

I know that the relation $d(PV) = SdT+Nd\mu+pdV $ holds for grand canonical ensemble but I could not go any further.

Answer (score 1):

It is a typical problem of thermodynamic manipulation.
You may start from the equality you mention (which is a thermodynamic equality independent on any ensemble you may choose to use), or even more simply, from the Gibbs-Duhem relation
$$
d\mu = -\frac{S}{N}dT + \frac{V}{N}dp.
$$
Whatever starting point is chosen, at constant $V$ and $T$,
$$
d\mu = \frac{V}{N}dp,
$$
which implies
$$
\left(\frac{\partial{\mu}}{\partial{N}}\right)_{V,T}=\frac{V}{N}\left(\frac{\partial{p}}{\partial{N}}\right)_{V,T}=-\frac{V}{N}
\frac{\left(\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{N}}\right)_{p,T}}{\left(\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{p}}\right)_{N,T}}=
-\frac{V}{N}\frac{\left(\frac{\partial{\mu}}{\partial{p}}\right)_{N,T}}{\left(\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{p}}\right)_{N,T}}=
-\frac{V}{N^2}\frac{\left(\frac{\partial{N\mu}}{\partial{p}}\right)_{N,T}}{\left(\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{p}}\right)_{N,T}}.
$$
By recalling that $G=N\mu$ and that $\left(\frac{\partial{G}}{\partial{p}}\right)_{N,T}=V$, we get the result.